# In C#, How should i close running threads ( Access DB )?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

VS 2008 / C# / MS Access 2003 / 2007

I have attached Code Snippet which throws exception on Release Mode. In Debug Mode, Application works great.

In order to test this piece of code, I moved to Console Application. When ever I run the application, it shows MS Access DB is already in Use.

So, before executing this piece of code, I need to Kill MS Access DB Process. Whether it is in use or not, I need to kill all the buffer process.

How should I kill the process before I execute this piece of code ?

```
try
    {

        Access.Application access1 = new Access.Application();

        // Open the Access database for exclusive access
        string sSalisburyAccessDB = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Salisbury.mdb");

        access1.OpenCurrentDatabase(sSalisburyAccessDB, true, null);

        // Drop the existing table data

        access1.DoCmd.DeleteObject(Access.AcObjectType.acTable, "drug");
        access1.DoCmd.DeleteObject(Access.AcObjectType.acTable, "patplan");
        access1.DoCmd.DeleteObject(Access.AcObjectType.acTable, "plans");
        access1.DoCmd.DeleteObject(Access.AcObjectType.acTable, "price");
        access1.DoCmd.DeleteObject(Access.AcObjectType.acTable, "rx");
        access1.DoCmd.DeleteObject(Access.AcObjectType.acTable, "patient");
        access1.DoCmd.DeleteObject(Access.AcObjectType.acTable, "plntrak");

        // Run the saved import
        access1.DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport("SalisburyODBC");

        // Close the database
        access1.CloseCurrentDatabase();

        // Quit MS Access
        access1.Quit(Access.AcQuitOption.acQuitSaveAll);

       Response.Write("successful");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anything in there that is likely not doable without automating Access. That is, you can delete tables with DAO and you can import/export data using plain old SQL statements. Automating Access looks like overkill to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue is you dont close the connection if an exception is raised in the main block. Try putting the access1.CloseCurrentDatabase(); in a finally block.

**EDIT** If you really want to kill the process then you can use [Process.Kill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx). I would recomend against it though as you could cause your users to lose data.

Comment: I know your not. Im saying you should to ensure the databse is closed

Comment: Actually, MSACCESS.EXE  process is keep running !! We need to force it to kill this .exe

Comment: @BrokenGlass, i didnt get you !!

Comment: @TomSquires, Okay i am using finally !! But still i face this issue !! Now, is there any way for us to force to kill the MSACCESS.EXE thread from C#