# MS Access application opened from Python script can't quit if Tk() loop is called

Tags: python, vba, ms-access, tkinter, createobject

I have stucked with a specific problem. I am working on Python script which reads data from MS Access database (.mdb) using VBA API and displays it in GUI tables using tkintertable module.

The problem is that after script terminates the MSACCESS.exe process is keeping alive in the process list.

When I comment mainloop() method for the root window the problem disappears.

Explicit call of access.quit() does not solve the problem. It makes it worse: the script terminates, but the MS Access process makes visible, I see it's window, but can't close it, because it appears more and more.

I removed all the unnecessary lines from the code to localize the problem:

```
#!C:\Python343\python
from comtypes.client import CreateObject
from tkinter import *

access = CreateObject('Access.Application')

root = Tk()
root.mainloop() # if I comment this line, everything works
# access.quit() - does not help: MS Access window gets visible and immortal
#
```

Can one give any clue of why this happens?
Thanks in advance for any advice.

Python version: 3.4.3.
MS Office: 2013.

Comment: Do you really need to create an instance of MSACCESS.exe? If you just want to read the data in an Access database you could use [pypyodbc](https://code.google.com/p/pypyodbc/) and the Microsoft Access Database Engine ODBC driver (which gets installed along with Microsoft Access).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't switch to pypyodbc or other packages, because the script is big and it is not convenient to redesign it. Now it uses VBA API (OpenRecordSet, MoveFirst, MoveLast methods etc.), but pypyodbc does not mirror this API AFAIK.

Now I use a workaround (killing of the MSACCESS.EXE application). I will post it here. Probably, it will be useful for one who stuck with the same problem:

```
def close_by_force(app): # Took this function from https://stackoverflow.com/
    # questions/10221150/cant-close-excel-completely-using-win32com-on-python,  
    # but had to redesign it to be usable to work with COM objects

import win32process
import win32gui
import win32api
import win32con

# Get the window's process id's
hwnd = app.hWndAccessApp()
t, p = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)
# Ask window nicely to close
win32gui.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_CLOSE, 0, 0)
# Allow some time for app to close
time.sleep(10) # not really necessary
# If the application didn't close, force close
try:
    #print('pid='+str(p))
    handle = win32api.OpenProcess(win32con.PROCESS_TERMINATE, 0, p)
    if handle:
        win32api.TerminateProcess(handle, 0)
        win32api.CloseHandle(handle)
except:
    pass

...
access = CreateObject('Access.Application')
DBEngine = access.DBEngine
db = DBEngine.OpenDatabase("C:\<my_db_path>")
.... some code (working with the database) ...
close_by_force(access.Application) # this is the crucial line
```

As I found in web, this problem is an old one and was discussed on different topics, but I don't see the exact solution anywhere, for example:

http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=298607

[In C#, How should i close running threads ( Access DB )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709939/in-c-how-should-i-close-running-threads-access-db)

http://python-list.python.narkive.com/gCMlrB8M/using-excel-with-python

Found also that I can use something like
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(access), but I can't found any link where may I get the related Python packages to use these classes.

--

Kind Regards,

Alexander.